# obtaining the results from one function and inputing it into another?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a class and a function and what I want to do is to "return" the value and input into another function.

```
Class test1 {

public function a($x) {
  $runquery = "Select * FROM testdb where color_id = '{$x}'";
    $result = mysql_query($runquery) or die(mysql_error());
    $base_results = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $red = $base_results['red'];

}

public function c($red) {
$runsecond_query = "SELECT * test2db where $color = '{$red}'";
// write additional code

}
```

OK, so really what I would LIKE to do is to get the results from function "a" and input the result in function "c". I hope that makes sense. Thanks to anyone in advance.

Comment: for the example used, it would probably be a lot easier for you to use a JOIN clause in your MySQL which just saves on number of functions being used and number of queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both functions are members of the same class, you can create a class property to store them:

```
Class test1 {

    // Private property to hold results
    private $last_result;

    public function a($x) {
      $runquery = "Select * FROM testdb where color_id = '{$x}'";
        $result = mysql_query($runquery) or die(mysql_error());
        $base_results = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        // Store your result into $this->last_result
        $this->last_result = $base_results['red'];
    }

    public function c() {
      $runsecond_query = "SELECT * test2db where $color = '{$this->last_result}'";
      // write additional code
    }
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU both so VERY much!! This is great

Comment: I am getting this error: Using $this when not in object context -- any ideas how to resolve?

Comment: Are you instantiating your class `test1`? Like:   `$t = new test1();  $t->a($x); $t->c();`

Answer (score 1):

```
function a($x) {
  ....
  return $red;
}

c(a($x));
```

or, if you want it to be a little more legible:

```
$red = a($x);
c($red);
```